# gomoku diagonal winning condition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

am currently working on a Gomoku game for windows and am using MFC. Am currently working on the winning algorithm for diagonals. My horizontal and vertical work just fine. Am hoping someone can help shade some light on where my logic is wrong. here is the code:

```
bool CMainFrame::isWinner(int player){
for (int row = 0; row < data.size(); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < data.size(); col++) {
        if (data[row][col].color == player && data[row + 1][col + 1].color == player && data[row + 2][col + 2].color == player && data[row + 3][col + 3].color == player && data[row + 4][col + 4].color == player) {
            CheckForGameOver(player); //function that simply shows message box of winning piece
            return true;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

It only works in the diagonal connected to the top left corner. Fairly new to programming so any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use numbers like `15` in your loops, use meaningful named constants, or derive the value from the size of your data.  A Go board is 19 x 19, so I'm not sure your test stays in bounds.

Comment: thanks for the response. my board is 15 X 15. oh I just edited out my data.size(). I use it in my code but it still doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Then you are definitely going out of bounds.

Comment: what may be the reason that the only diagonal that works is the one that starts from the top left corner?

Comment: sorry I don't understand how it goes out of bounds. do you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: I know this from your previous question but it would help to make MCVE (not for the whole game) to show the problem.

Comment: `data[row+4][col+4]` is out of bounds when either row or col > 10.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani alright will do so

Comment: @stark I see... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules of this game is that 5 items should match in a row, or in a column, or in a diagonal line. Just compare each row, column, and diagonal line to see if 5 items match, and return true. Otherwise the function should return false.

```
bool won(std::vector<std::vector<data_t>> &data, int color)
{
    //check each row:
    for(int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                if(color != data[row][col + i].color)
                    match = false;
            if(match) return true;
        }
    //check each column:
    for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        for(int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                if(color == data[row + i][col].color)
                    match = false;
            if(match) return true;
        }
    //check diagonal lines from top-left to bottom-right
    for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                if(color == data[row + i][col + i].color)
                    match = false;
            if(match) return true;
        }
    //lastly check diagonal lines from top-right to bottom-left
    return false;
}
```